How to create GKE node pool using another subnetwork?
I have a GKE cluster with two node pools. In this cluster, I am using only one subnetwork (US) with the range 10.100.100.0/24, and all 254 IP addresses are in use because I am also using this subnetwork for VMs along with Kubernetes.
I need to create new node pools, but I receive an error because of the exhausted IP addresses.
us-central1-a: Requested resource is exhausted: Not all instances running in IGM after 58.156203563s. Expected 2, running 0, transitioning 2. Current errors: [IP_SPACE_EXHAUSTED]: Instance 'gke-us-xxx-38de9507-wxwr' creation failed: IP space of 'projects/xxx-yyy/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/us' is exhausted. .; us-central1-b: Requested resource is exhausted: Not all instances running in IGM after 44.519059343s. Expected 2, running 0, transitioning 2. Current errors: [IP_SPACE_EXHAUSTED]: Instance 'gke-us-xxx-4f57c3c6-6zq4' creation failed: IP space of 'projects/xxx-yyy/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/us' is exhausted.

I can't recreate this cluster with a new, bigger subnetwork because it is in production already.
I want to create a new subnetwork, like US2 with the range 10.100.101.0/24, and use it for the new node pools, but i didn't find how to pass different to the new node pools. I am using Terraform with the 'google_container_node_pool' resource
I thought to use 'additional_node_network_configs' in 'network_config' but this is really additional subnetwork, not replacing old one
Here is the code, we created a module GKE
resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  location = var.region

  network           = var.network_id
  subnetwork        = var.subnetwork_id
  datapath_provider = "ADVANCED_DATAPATH"

  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
  enable_shielded_nodes    = true

  min_master_version = var.cluster_version

  logging_config {
    enable_components = [
      "SYSTEM_COMPONENTS",
    ]
  }

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = "pod-network"
    services_secondary_range_name = "service-network"
  }

  master_authorized_networks_config {
    dynamic "cidr_blocks" {
      for_each = var.master_authorized_networks_cidr_blocks
      content {
        cidr_block   = cidr_blocks.value.cidr_block
        display_name = cidr_blocks.value.display_name
      }
    }
  }

  release_channel {
    channel = "UNSPECIFIED"
  }
  # real Cyprus winter time +2, summer time +3
  maintenance_policy {
    recurring_window {
      start_time = var.maintenance_recurring_window.start_time
      end_time   = var.maintenance_recurring_window.end_time
      recurrence = var.maintenance_recurring_window.recurrence

    }
  }

  notification_config {
    pubsub {
      enabled = var.notification_enabled
      topic   = "projects/${var.project}/topics/${var.notification_topic}"

      filter {
        event_type = var.notification_filter
      }
    }

  }


  # Disable basic authentication and cert-based authentication.
  master_auth {
    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes    = true
    enable_private_endpoint = false
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = var.master_ipv4_cidr_block
  }

  addons_config {

    gcs_fuse_csi_driver_config {
      enabled = true
    }

    horizontal_pod_autoscaling {
      disabled = true
    }

    http_load_balancing {
      disabled = !var.glb_ingress
    }

    network_policy_config {
      disabled = true
    }

    cloudrun_config {
      disabled = true
    }
  }

  workload_identity_config {
    workload_pool = "${var.project}.svc.id.goog"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes  = [node_config]
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "nodes" {
  for_each          = var.node_pools
  cluster           = google_container_cluster.cluster.id
  name              = each.key
  node_count        = each.value.node_count
  max_pods_per_node = each.value.max_pods_per_node

  management {
    auto_repair  = true
    auto_upgrade = false
  }

  node_config {
    machine_type    = each.value.machine_type
    disk_type       = "pd-ssd"
    disk_size_gb    = each.value.disk_size_gb
    labels          = each.value.labels
    tags            = [var.cluster_machine_tag]
    service_account = var.service_account != "" ? var.service_account : google_service_account.cluster_machine.email
    spot            = each.value.spot

    dynamic "taint" {
      for_each = each.value.taint
      content {
        key    = taint.value.key
        value  = taint.value.value
        effect = taint.value.effect
      }
    }

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    ]

    shielded_instance_config {
      enable_integrity_monitoring = true
      enable_secure_boot          = true
    }

    metadata = {
      "disable-legacy-endpoints" = "true"
    }
  }
}


If possible can you update your question with tf configuration files ?

update main post with terraform code, this is part of module GKE, which we call in our projects
